values of a 1-D column coerced to zeros on appending to Pandas dataframe
# set the targets: normal=0, tumor=1

y_normal = np.zeros(6485)

y_tumor = np.ones(1348)

combined_targets = np.concatenate([y_normal,y_tumor],axis=0)

combined_targets.shape

combined_targets = pd.DataFrame(combined_targets)
combined_targets.columns = ["target"]

combined_targets.value_counts()

final_train_df = combined_df
final_train_df["target"]= combined_targets

final_train_df['target'].value_counts()

If I directly assign, then the values do not change
final_train_df['target'] = np.concatenate([y_normal,y_tumor],axis=0)

The dataframe is available here
sample dataset
value of column changes
The ones in a column created by numpy and then converted to a dataframe, are coerced to zeros. even adding as a np.array, the values are coerced to zeros. I am working in google colab and I have not faced this issue before

Images of code/data are not acceptable, please provide a [mre]. We should be able to copy/paste your code and get the same output as you currently have. Don't forget to provide a example combined_targets.

Dear  @mozway, Thanks for correcting. I have updated my question

if I directly assign the column to the dataframe, then the values are not converted.

chk print(len(final_train_df)) & print(final_traub)df.index.nunique()). I guess due to duplicate indexes
